# DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting this error DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.  Still VERY green when it comes to using ASP.NET MVC so I am not understanding what is happening and why I am getting this error.  Been scouring forums but nothing is really making sense.  Using ADO.Net Entity Model.  Entity Framework 6.

**Controller**

```
readonly StatsEntity1 _db = new StatsEntity1();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var statsC = (from n in _db.WKLY_STATSTC
                  where n.TERM == "14"&& n.GRP=="C"
                  select n.TERM into w
                  select new { Count = w.Count() });

    var statsN = (from n in _db.WKLY_STATSTC
                  where n.TERM == "14" && n.GRP == "N"
                  select n.TERM into w
                  select new { Count = w.Count() });

    ViewBag.StatsC = statsC;
    ViewBag.StatsN = statsN;
    return View("Index");
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Reports.Models.WKLY_STATSTC>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@ViewBag.StatsC</td>
        <td>@ViewBag.StatsN</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what you need is getting the count of the query.

```
       var statsC = (from n in _db.WKLY_STATSTC
                    where n.TERM == "14" &&
                            n.GRP == "C"
                    select n.TERM).Count();

        var statsN = (from n in _db.WKLY_STATSTC
                     where n.TERM == "14" &&
                             n.GRP == "N"
                     select n.TERM).Count();
```

Unless what you need is really array of `n.Term` length.

```
       var statsC = (from n in _db.WKLY_STATSTC
                    where n.TERM == "14" &&
                            n.GRP == "C"
                    select n.TERM into w

                    select new { Count = w.Length }).ToArray();

        var statsN = (from n in _db.WKLY_STATSTC
                     where n.TERM == "14" &&
                             n.GRP == "N"
                     select n.TERM into w

                     select new { Count = w.Length }).ToArray();
```

Comment: The first one did it.  Just needed a simple count and return the result to a table in the view.  Thank you!

Comment: @miagriff, in that case, the `select n.TERM` can also be omitted